# Unlock Jenkins page keep loading every time even after admin user and password is created

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I am creating jenkins agent in kubernetes. First time unlock jenkins page loaded and ask for admin password
from the command prompt using kubectl logs command I have generated password

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX0M5.png)

The password I have entered unlock Jenkins page. Then I created user admin and the password then went into manage Jenkins page installed all default plugins also installed Kubernetes plugins.

after that I restarted but again its loading the Unlock Jenkins page and again the cycle continues.

Why it  keep loading the unlock Jenkins page how to resolve the issue.
also the login page keep loading continuously even i give correct uid and pwd its says invalid after repeated attempts it login again if i click manage jenkins again this login page loads getting annoyed dont know how to fix this issues.
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qDCK.png)

My config.xml

```
<securityRealm class="hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm">
<disableSignup>true</disableSignup>
<enableCaptcha>false</enableCaptcha>
</securityRealm>
<disableRememberMe>false</disableRememberMe>
<projectNamingStrategy class="jenkins.model.ProjectNamingStrategy$DefaultProjectNamingStrategy"/>
<workspaceDir>${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</workspaceDir>
<buildsDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds</buildsDir>
<jdks/>
<viewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultViewsTabBar"/>
<myViewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultMyViewsTabBar"/>
<clouds/>
<scmCheckoutRetryCount>0</scmCheckoutRetryCount>
<views>
<hudson.model.AllView>
  <owner class="hudson" reference="../../.."/>
  <name>all</name>
  <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
  <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
  <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
</hudson.model.AllView>
</views>
<primaryView>all</primaryView>
<slaveAgentPort>50000</slaveAgentPort>
<label></label>
<crumbIssuer class="hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer">
<excludeClientIPFromCrumb>false</excludeClientIPFromCrumb>
</crumbIssuer>
<nodeProperties/>
<globalNodeProperties/>
<nodeRenameMigrationNeeded>false</nodeRenameMigrationNeeded>
</hudson>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you pass the Jenkins logs? These are typically located in /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log for a local installation.
Try searching the startup log and see why it is not booting correctly.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, i have edited my post with config,xml